# Valid/invalid non-ascii and invalid ascii characters

Tags: java, string, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I need to test the processing of a string which contains `valid non-ascii characters + invalid non-ascii characters + invalid ascii characters`.

Can someone please give me a couple of examples of such characters. It would be great if you could let me know the range of their value in their category as I am not quite able to differentiate which non-ascii values could be valid and which ones are invalid.

```
Ex : String str = "Bj��rk����oacute�";
                       ^ 
                       Is it a valid or invalid non-ascii
```

FYI I am a beginner in Java.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of each (valid non-ascii, invalid non-ascii, invalid ascii)?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because you didn't provide any examples of what you're looking for, as well as not showing any form of attempt.

Comment: There is the Character class in Java that has multiple methods that can determine that. For example tell if it is a whitespace or a control character. Depends on what is 'non-ascii' for you?

Comment: Possibly you may want to state which character set the string is referring to. A character in a character set could be 'valid' while not 'valid' in another character set. Then define what 'valid' means.

Comment: I think your confusion comes from the requirement statement using "ASCII" to mean characters in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block, when ASCII is a different character set than is used in Java. But, also what does "valid" mean in your project? (� is a valid character but is most often used to indicate that some buggy code mishandled the user's data.)

Answer (score 1):

There are 128 valid basic ASCII characters, mapped to the values 0 (the `NUL` byte) to 127 (the `DEL` character). [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

The word 'character' must be used wisely. The definition of 'character' is a special one. For example, the `è`, is that one character? Or is it two characters (`e` and `` ` ``)? It depends.

Secondly, a sequence of characters is completely independent from its encoding. For simplicity, I assume that each byte is interpreted as one character.

You can determine if a byte can be parsed as an ASCII character, you can simply do this:

```
byte[] bytes = "Bj��rk����oacute�".getBytes();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    // What's happening here? A byte that is in the range from 0 to 127 is
    // valid, and other values are invalid. A byte in Java is signed, that
    // means that valid ranges are from -128 to 127.
    if (b >= 0) {
        System.out.println("Valid ASCII");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid ASCII");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Some background***

As Java was invented, a very important design decision was that text in java would be Unicode: a numbering system of all graphemes in the world. Hence `char` is two bytes (in UTF-16, one of the Unicode "universal character set transformation format"). And `byte` is a distinct type for binary data.

Unicode numbers all symbols, so-called **code points**, like `♫`, as U+266B. Those numbers reaching the three byte integers. Hence code points in java are represented as `int`.

**ASCII** is a 7-bits subset of Unicode UTF-8, 0 - 127.

**UTF-8** is a multibyte Unicode format, where ASCII is a valid subset, and higher symbols

***Validity***

You were asked to identify *"invalid" characters* = wrongly produced code points.
You could also identify *code parts* that produce invalid characters. (Easier.)

In the above `�` is a place holder character (like `?`) that substitutes a code point not being representable in the current character set. If the code produced a `?` as place holder, one cannot guess whether substitution took place. For some west European languages the encoding is Windows-1252 (Cp1252, MS Windows Latin-1) having. You can check whether a code point from a String can be converted to that `Charset`.

Then remain false positives, wrong characters that however exist in Cp1252. That could be a multi-byte code sequence of UTF-8, interpreted as several Window-1252 characters. So: **an acceptable non-ASCII char adjacent to a unacceptable non-ASCII char is suspect too**. That means you need to list the special characters in your language, and extras: like special quotes, in English borrows like `ç`, `ñ`.

For MS-Windows Latin-1 (an altered ISO Latin-1) something like:

```
boolean isSuspect(char ch) {
    if (ch < 32) {
        return "\f\n\r\t".indexOf(ch) != -1;
    } else if (ch >= 127) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return suspects.get((int) ch); // Better use a positive list.
    }
}

static BitSet suspects = new BitSet(256);
static {
    ...
}
```